# What is the difference between an Android Native Browser and the WebView in an Android Application in terms of their functions?

Tags: android, browser, webview

I guess both Android Native Browser and the WebView uses the same webkit.

But I want to know how are they different in terms of their functionalities.

Are they one and the same or does webview has additional uses and functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

Go for Webview when you are required to update small part of the page.. else you can go for browser intent.